# Invalid character in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Here, when i execute this query it is showing me invalid character. how to solve is error.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO' ||VAR_L_COUNT||'FROM'|| P_TABLE ||
                     ' WHERE  ' || AMOUNT || ' > ' ||  LIMIT_AMT  ||  ' AND  EMPID =  '''||  VAR_PI_EMPID||''';');
RETURN VAR_L_COUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, not like that, as you noticed.

- it seems that this is part of a function, according to parameters you used (e.g. `p_table`, `limit_amt`, `var_pi_empid`); usually, it helps if you post the whole code
- as kpasha commented, you missed to provide spaces between keywords and the rest of the command; obvious mistake is with the `from` clause
- in dynamic SQL, you don't `insert into` within the statement, but when executing it
- beware of SQL injection; use `dbms_assert` package and bind variables, where appropriate
- dynamic SQL statements can't end with a semi-colon
- instead of multiplying single quotes, consider using the q-quoting mechanism
- for debugging purposes, it is good to compose the whole statement in a local variable, display it (using `dbms_output.put_line`) or use it as *return value* of the function so that you could review it first, and then - once you're sure everything is OK - execute it.

Here's a working example; it might need to be modified, depending on what you really have in your schema/table.

Sample data:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM some_table;

EMPID          AMOUNT
---------- ----------
1                 100
2                 200
3                 300
```

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (p_table      IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                     p_limit_amt  IN NUMBER,
  3                                     p_empid      IN NUMBER)
  4     RETURN NUMBER
  5  IS
  6     l_str        VARCHAR2 (500);
  7     var_l_count  NUMBER;
  8  BEGIN
  9     l_str :=
 10           'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
 11        || DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (p_table)
 12        || ' WHERE amount > '
 13        || p_limit_amt
 14        || ' AND empid =  :a';
 15
 16     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
 17        INTO var_l_count
 18        USING p_empid;
 19
 20     RETURN var_l_count;
 21  END;
 22  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT f_test ('some_table', 50, '1') result FROM DUAL;

    RESULT
----------
         1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use bind variables where ever possible.
2. Sanitise your input where you cannot.
3. Don't include the statement terminator (`;`) in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` code.
4. As already mentioned, you have missed spaces between the literals and the concatenated variables.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION function_name(
  p_table      IN VARCHAR2,
  amount       IN NUMBER,
  limit_amt    IN NUMBER,
  var_pi_empid IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  var_l_count NUMBER(10,0);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*)'
                || ' FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(p_table)
                || ' WHERE  :1 > :2'
                || ' AND    EMPID =  :3'
    INTO  var_l_count
    USING amount, limit_amt, var_pi_empid;

  RETURN VAR_L_COUNT;
END;
/
```

If `amount` or `limit_amt` are columns (and not variables) then don't pass them as variables:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION function_name(
  p_table      IN VARCHAR2,
  var_pi_empid IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
  var_l_count NUMBER(10,0);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*)'
                || ' FROM ' || DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME(p_table)
                || ' WHERE  amount > limit_amt'
                || ' AND    EMPID =  :1'
    INTO  var_l_count
    USING var_pi_empid;

  RETURN VAR_L_COUNT;
END;
/
```